# Looking at image thumbnails in the Files / Nautilus app

Tags: files

I have just had Ubuntu installed on my laptop on which I used to have Windows 7.

My question is this: with Windows 7, when I went to my `Pictures` folder, I would see all the pictures in the folder, in their folders, as very small thumbnails, with the number of the files underneath. If I wanted to see one of these pictures in larger format I could click on it.

With Ubuntu, when I go to my `Pictures` folder, what I get is a listing of the pictures in the folder, with just the file number and the date it was put in the file. I can't figure out how to actually see the picture that is in that folder.

How do I actually look at the picture in that folder? Ideally I would like to be able to look at all the pictures at once, as very small thumbnails, as I could with Windows 7, and then pick out the one I wanted to see it larger.

Is there a way to do what I want with Ubuntu?

Comment: There is probably an image viewer installed by default in whatever Ubuntu distribution you are using, otherwise just try installing one like gwenview or gthumb. Tried double-clicking on an image file yet?

Comment: All he needs is already built-in. He just needs guidance on how to switch between list-view vs thumbnail view in the file manager.

Answer (score 4):

In the file browser, aptly names *Files*, click the menu at the upper right and select Preferences. Under Preferences, select Search & Preview. Select Thumbnails, for example, Files on this computer only.

Close and restart *Files* and the preview should now be visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the Pictures folder,

click the button near the top right corner of the window, marked with green arrow:

[image: File browser thumbnail mode toggle button]

---

Alternatively, press these keys together:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>

for seeing the small preview of pictures (they are called "thumbnails")

and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>

to return to the list view where the filenames are listed under each other.